# window.open is not applying the given height parameter

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have a onclick event on a link inwhich window.open for a url is executed , I have also given the custom width and height for it, but is not accepting it and pop window is displayed with different width and height.. can someone guide me what must be wrong with that

my window.open syntax is as follows

```
onclick='var myW=window.open ("http://www.google.co.jp/","mywindow","location=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=846,height=786");
```

Also how to change the display position of pop window in the screen?

> NOTE: AFTER ALL THE REPLIES Being Positive with my code.. I tried it
>   and found after thinking about it that whatever size I was giving in
>   parameter the browser taking it more than that... May be thats due to
>   resolution....

Comment: It's working for me. Also, you can use `top` and `left` to position it.

Comment: No Its not working It takes the height of original window and width slightly higher than mention in paraeter

Comment: Hi OM ,Adjust the values of top and left

Comment: @OMTheEternity what was the issue ? How did u fix this ?  Even I am facing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is working fine :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="cl" onclick='var myW=window.open 

("http://www.google.co.jp/","mywindow","location=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=200,height=200");'>
</body>
</html>
```

for more check this:- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
to window position a pop up window just after it opens use:-

```
window.moveTo(50,50);//your window object:-
```

The parameters for the moveTo are the left position followed by the top position for the top left corner of the window.

Comment: No Its not working It takes the height of original window and width slightly higher than mention in paraeter

Comment: try this link and see whether you are getting same :- http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus

Answer (score 1):

```
function mypopup()
{
    mywindow = window.open("http://www.javascript-coder.com", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,  width=100,height=100");
    mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
```

The code positions the popup on the top left corner of the screen with width and height 100px.

Comment: No Its not working It takes the height of original window and width slightly higher than mention in paraeter

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function popup_win()
     {
         var mywdw = window.open("http://www.google.com/", "mywindow", "location=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=100,height=100,top=250, left=350");
     }
```

Comment: It is Working on FF and Chrome also

Comment: No Its not working It takes the height of original window and width slightly higher than mention in paraeter

Answer (score 0):

*(following may not be related to OP 's case)*

note: **make sure you close your `previous popup window`**.

if, say,

1. you clicked on an element to open the `popup window` & didnt close it,
2. and you change the width/height in your code,
3. and you re-run/refresh the html,
4. and you click on the same element to open a `popup window` (-- `window.open` the same `target`)
5. -> the browser will **re-use the `prev popup window` 's width/height**