# How to fix the position of the web page?

Tags: asp.net

In web applicatin, i am trying to open a web page using javascript like this :

```
OnClientClick="window.open('chat.aspx', 'OtherPage','width=400,Height=440,Top=350,left=0,titlebar=no,menubar=yes,location=no,resizable=no,channelmode=no,directories=no,status=no,scrollbar=no');"
```

now i want to fix the position of the web page to right side  corner of the system is it possible, please help me.

Comment: See this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612745/window-open-is-not-applying-the-given-height-parameter/9612869#9612869

Answer (score 0):

```
function popup( width, height, url ) {
var left=screen.width-width;
var top=screen.height-height;
var pWin=open( url, 'win', 'width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',t op='+top );
if( pWin.screenX != null ) {
pWin.screenX=left;
pWin.screenY=top;
}
}
```

You will end up with a window that is at least approximately in the
lower right corner of the screen, with variations depending on the
exact browser used. This may or may not be acceptable for your
purposes; it's something to work from. Notice, in any case, that it
works reasonably in Firefox and IE.